# How to Use ngFor for multiple components?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

So, i'm trying to use `ngFor` for 10 different components.

Something like that:

```
<ion-slide class="page-slide" *ngFor="let item of slideArr">
 <ion-card class="page-slide-card">
  <ion-card-content> {{item.title}}
    <component of number x></component of number x>
  </ion-card-content>
 </ion-card>
</ion-slide>
```

There are 10 components. Each one for each ion-slide. Is there a way other than `ngIf` to make them load on screen?

Comment: I'd say abstract a common component and pass the data specific to each iteration using `@Input()` instead of having 10 different components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these different components? In that case NgSwitch might be useful.

https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch